Use of python property decorator for non-class attributes
Simple one that's been annoying me when I see it:
Is it correct or pythonic to use the property decorator outside the getter/setter context where you are not returning a protected class attribute. For example:
class ExampleWithUnnecessaryProperty:

    def __init__(self, a: str):
        self._a = a  # protected attribute

    # This feels wrong to me - could be class attr, global const
    @property
    def arbitrary_attr(self) -> int:
        return 5

    # This also feels wrong to me - could be helper func
    @property
    def arbitrary_method(self) -> str:
        return 5 * self.a

    # use as a getter of protected attrs
    @property
    def a(self) -> str:
        return self._a

    # setter dependant on getter - also makes perfect sense to me
    @a.setter
    def a.setter(self, value: str) -> None:
        self._a = value

Any thoughts or links to relevant documentation?
This is the best I can find: https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Python_Language_OOP_Attributes_and_Properties#:~:text=to%20Use%20Properties.-,When%20to%20Use%20Attributes%20and%20When%20to%20Use%20Properties,is%20retrieved%2C%20set%20or%20deleted.

No, I see no case in which this makes sense. Where did you find this?

Normal attributes and global variables are writable, whereas a property with no setter/deleter is read only. Also, a property can have a doc-string. The exact way in which the returned value is computed is an implementation detail, so it doesn't seem an important consideration. A class that defines read-only constants with run-time documentation (e.g. via help(MyClass)), seems perfectly reasonable. Writing to such constants would normally be a bug, so raising an exception is better than just failing silently. Normal attributes and global variables can't provide any of these benefits.

The point of properties is that the user doesn't need to know how it's implemented. Just because it could be a helper function doesn't mean you want to expose that to the users. You want them to use it as if it's an attribute. This allows you to change the implementation without them having to change how they use it. It's an abstraction or information-hiding technique.

@Barmar ... and if the property is only called inside another method within the same class - would this still be a use case?

Even within the same class, there are modularity benefits. It's the same reason you might call a method of the class rather than duplicating code.

Also, you can override the property in a subclass.
